# Maximize a table

Tags: calculus, optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

I am studying the max-sum algorithm to solve Distributed Constraint Optimization Problem. I have a very basic doubt about the maximization of a function w.r.t. a single variable. Consider the constraints F(x1,x2) with x1={a,b} and x2={a,b} represented by the following table:

[image]

We want to maximize the table w.r.t to x2.
I have an exercise provided me by a friend of mine. The solution is:

[image]

Is this solution right? My doubt concerns the fact that we have chosen the value x1=a to maximize x2=a (first line on the table) whereas we have chosen x1=b to maximize x2=b. Is it "legal" (mathematically correct) to "assign" two different values to x1 in order to maximize the table?

Comment: The given answer is maximizing with respect to $x_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial function is $F(x_1,x_2)$. The function in the second table is:
$$G(x_2) = \max_{x_1} F(x_1,x_2).$$
The function $G$ depends only on $x_2$. A version of your table with a correct header is:

[image]

Comment: I got the impression that both the OP and you mixed up $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @BenoitGaudeul you can argue about what OP wants exactly ("We want to maximize the table w.r.t to x2"), but if his example table is what he is looking for, my answer is mathematically correct.

Comment: My bad. I thought his first column was $\arg\max f$.

Comment: @BenoitGaudeul I had not thought of that, but you could indeed create a table with columns $x_1$, $argmax_{x_2} F(x1,x2)$ and $F(x1,argmax_{x_2} F(x1,x2))$ (where argmax returns a single element instead of a set). If you remove the first column, the table is the same as my table.